# in multithreading killing thread respectivly though cpuutilization is much more greater

Tags: java, multithreading, cpu-usage

i had create the Billing interface which having tcp/ip protocol as well as http so for tcp/ip protocol  i created the multi-threading and i m killing thread safely after requierments over but due to this thing i think cpu utilization is much more greater please anyone guide me on this. what are the reason for high cpu usage ? thanks in advance and how to resolve ? i m newbee!

Comment: If you use more threads that do more CPU intensive work, you're going to have higher CPU utilisation.

Comment: Network interfaces are not, usually CPU-intensive.  Whay might be going on with the DB/SQL for the billing is another matter:(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to investigate high CPU usage I suggest you use a CPU profiler. There is a free one in VisualVM. When it comes to understanding your application's usage you have to measure it, otherwise you are just guessing.

Comment: i checked on server its Linux with commands this interface only have more cpu-utilization !!!